# Pandas histogram by dates, and sorted by categories

Tags: python, pandas, histogram

I'm having trouble probably with understanding grouping in pandas, and also being able to produce histograms that are stacked by category.

Here's a working example of what I am trying to do. Really I am looping over many files, from each one I create a dictionary, and then append that to a list with all the dictionaries. Then I turn that into a dataframe and convert date strings to datetime objects.

```
import pandas as pd

# Stand in for dictionaries created by looping over some files
d1={'fruit':'banana','vege':'spinach','date':'August 1, 2014'}
d2={'fruit':'banana','vege':'carrots','date':'August 1, 2014'}
d3={'fruit':'banana','vege':'peas','date':'August 1, 2015'}
d4={'fruit':'orange','vege':'spinach','date':'August 1, 2014'}
d5={'fruit':'orange','vege':'carrots','date':'August 1, 2015'}
data=[d1,d2,d3,d4,d5]

# Create the dataframe, turn the date strings into datetime objects
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
df.date2=pd.to_datetime(df.date) 

# This attempt at plotting gets me a histogram by year, but not divided how it should be.
df.groupby(df.date2.dt.year).count().plot(kind="bar")
```

The resulting plot looks like this:

[image: Histogram by year, but unsure why 3 bars for each with category labels]

What I'd really like is something like this:

[image: Histogram by year, stacked by the text within the category of "fruit"]

I've tried various other things, such as

```
fr=df.groupby('fruit')
```

But then fr.plot fails because

```
TypeError: Empty 'DataFrame': no numeric data to plot
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about:

```
df.groupby(df.date2.dt.year)['fruit']\
    .value_counts()\
    .unstack(1)\
    .plot(kind='bar', stacked=True)
```

Which yields:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using `date` as `DateTimeIndex`. For `pandas 0.17`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date).dt.year
df.set_index('date', inplace=True)
df.groupby(level='date').fruit.value_counts().unstack('fruit').plot.bar(stacked=True)
```

[image]

Comment: Unsure if it is a difference in pandas or python version, but your last line did not work for me. However, it does work if I do: df.groupby(level='date').fruit.value_counts().unstack().plot(kind='bar',stacked=True). I encounter an error if I include 'fruit' in the unstack parantheses, and also an error if I do plot.bar. Using pandas version 0.16.1.